# mean.io force authentication

Tags: angularjs, passport.js, mean-stack, mean.io

mean.io has integrated authentication and it's working ok, but it has public and private pages. What can be done to force authentication for all pages (including public ones) so that user is instantly redirected to login?

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to use interceptor as explained here
http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/

but then need to figure out how to check if user is logged in and forward request

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
  $provide.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {
        return config || $q.when(config);
      },
      // On request failure
      requestError: function (rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
      response: function (response) {
        return response || $q.when(response);
      },
      responseError: function (rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  });
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');
});
```